# How to show a Holo (dark) AlertDialog in a themed activity?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have tried to use a content wrapper:

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(wrapper);
```

The result of this, is a dialog box of a mix of both dark and white, horrible.

I have also tried using customized styles and etc in the past 2 hours, no luck. I believe the solution must be very simple, I just need to trick the AlertDialog Builder to think my activity is Holo dark themed. But how?

[image]

This is how I themed my activity, maybe I did something wrong there:

```
<style name="ThemeSolarizedLight" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/light_yellow</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">that No Wi-fi color you see up there</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the actionbar's theme instead use the theme made for dialog

**sample:**

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog;);
```

Comment: Tried this, exactly the same result.

Comment: @user1032613 make a theme inside your style.xml for your dialog and use it