# AlertDialog with custom layout doesn't render properly (a border gets added)

Tags: android, android-view, android-alertdialog

I'm currently having a problem when I try to use the `AlertDialog.setView(View v)` function.

When the dialog is rendered, no matter the theme used, it generates a border around the layout, just as if another layout was encapsulating it.

Using `builder.show()` alone, `builder.create()` alone or both together yields the same results.

Am I missing something somewhere, or is it a known bug ? Thanks in advance if you can help.

dialog_status.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerStatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextStatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Status"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxStatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="@string/save_status"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code inside Activity :

```
private void showStatusDialog(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
    //AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); (Yields the same results, just another theme)
    View root = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dialog_status, null);

    final EditText input = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.editTextStatus);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.spinnerStatus);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) root.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxStatus);
    final Preferences p = new Preferences(FChatActivity.this);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            input.setText(p.getDefaultStatusMessage(FCharacter.Status.getIdentifiers().get(i)));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.addAll(FCharacter.Status.getLabels());
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    builder.setView(root)
            .setMessage("Update your status")
            .setTitle("Status")
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    setStatus(FCharacter.Status.getIdentifiers().get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()),input.getText().toString(), checkBox.isChecked());
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });

    builder.create();
    builder.show();
}
```

Screenshots :

[image: Theme_Holo_Dialog]
[image: Theme_Diialog]

Comment: I think you must change the theme you're using here `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);` instead of using `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog`

Comment: Changing the theme doesn't change anything, I'm adding another screenshot to show you

Comment: You can try like this . `String info = cityData.getPointerList().get(position).toString();  
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CityActivity.this).create();  
alertDialog.show();  
Window window = alertDialog.getWindow();  
window.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main_info);  
TextView tv_title = (TextView) window.findViewById(R.id.tv_dialog_title);  
tv_title.setText("detail info");  
TextView tv_message = (TextView) window.findViewById(R.id.tv_dialog_message);  
tv_message.setText(info); `

Comment: Using setContentView() on the generated AlertDialog doesn't work, as i need to pass a View, and not a Layout ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution on another completely unrelated question ([How to show a Holo (dark) AlertDialog in a themed activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473254/how-to-show-a-holo-dark-alertdialog-in-a-themed-activity)) :

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(wrapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Create a new style in `styles.xml` like

```
<style name="Dialog.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

> Then use the style in your `AlertDialog` like.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Dialog_NoActionBar);
```

hope this can help.

Comment: `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` and `android:windowTranslucentStatus` require API 19, and my minimal target is 16, and I need to target that low

Comment: Ohh, I see I think this is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/13763132/5693082 Just remove the `android:windowTranslucentStatus` and `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds`

Comment: If you see my answer, I already found a far simpler solution that seems to be the right way, but thanks for your help